# Sendmail is not working in PHP 7.1 CLI (SSH)

Tags: php, command-line-interface, sendmail

I have opened a `tmux` screen and started my newsletter. It uses the `mail()` php function in order to send the emails to 500,000 destinations. It should take normally no more than a day to do so.

However, I've upgraded my VPS and had to reset all my data and settings, so now I'm trying to send mail again using the same method as before (installed  `sendmail`, etc) and now I'm getting a `deferred connection timed out` on the log files at `/var/log/mail.log`.

I tried scanning my ports to check if they're open; yes they are, I did a `telnet localhost 25` and it worked, however, I tried for example `telnet smtp.gmail.com 25` and it tries to establish a connection but fails, returning a timed out error.

I'm using the Ultimate plan of [GoDaddy's servers](https://godaddy.com) Linux Ubuntu 14.04.

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 2):

I had to undergo similar situation for mailenable http://www.windowstechinfo.com/2014/09/mailenable-smtp-error-10060-godaddy.html

Godaddy servers - **they don't allow outbound 25 port SMTP from most of their servers.** use port 587 might work
else 
you have to go through godaddys  relay server.

https://www.godaddy.com/help/find-your-email-relay-server-122

you have to change settings in Sendmail to use relay server.

you have to define `SMART_HOST` in sendmail 
https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/sendmail-relay-to-godaddy-788580/

Contact go daddy for more details

ps :
also i dont think godaddy is favourable if you are going to send `500000 emails` per day...

"Our servers have an outbound email limit of 1000 per day. If you need to send more than 1000 emails per day, contact customer support." source https://sg.godaddy.com/help/find-your-email-relay-server-122

https://www.godaddy.com/help/how-many-email-messages-can-i-send-per-day-313
https://sg.godaddy.com/help/how-many-email-messages-can-i-send-per-day-313

Comment: im the same who made the question, I dont have an account and i logged out when refreshing page so cant comment: **I have purchased a server for 12 months and need to send high volume emails. Is there any alternative or else how can you do it with the 587 port? I really dont understand much what you say, maybe you're not clear and confuses me.
Thanks in advance**

Comment: We dont know what type of server you have purchased , thus cant predict port 25/587 will work. contact support from godaddy and carefully go through the links. and if you dont understand try to get help from someone who can assist you .. this is mentioned in relay server link below "Our servers have an outbound email limit of 1000 per day. If you need to send more than 1000 emails per day, contact customer support."

Comment: by the way godaddy has a great support staff and even they will help you .. use below answer directions to get support .